# Fail to alert a mensage on cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to make this simple test on cordova, but it does not work:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);
function init(){
  alert('Done');
}
```

Comment: The question is too broad. Any error is shown?

Comment: No error, just nothing happens, but I've already solved this by changing false to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code is working fine and the thing is we cannot call 2 deviceready at a time

```
`       <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>`
```

In cordova basically the device ready function  by default mentioned in index.js file and suppose if you the same deviceready function on a external **script.js** it wont run . If u comment the index.js and run the program then you will get you alert.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the false option to true, like this:

window.addEventListener("deviceready",init,false);

I don't know why, but now that is working...